# Google ads skript Low Volume Campaingn

Tags: google-ads-api, google-ads-script, google-ads-data-hub

I have a problem with my function that pulls out all low-volume products from Google Ads. I want the low-volume products to be automatically labeled, so I need to compare their IDs. However, the IDs extracted from the Google Shopping report are only in lowercase, but I need them in their original form with both uppercase and lowercase letters. For example, the IDs are aA4654BhZ. Can someone help me to get them in the correct case so they can match? Here's my script:

```
var SPREADSHEET_URL ="GOOGLE SHEET EINFÜGEN"
var FILTERS = "Impressions < 50";
var TIME_DURATION = "LAST_30_DAYS";
var COUNT_LIMIT = 999999;

function main(){
var products = getFilteredShoppingProducts();
products.sort(function(a,b){return a[0] > b[0];});
products = products.slice(0, COUNT_LIMIT);
pushToSpreadsheet(products);
}

function getFilteredShoppingProducts(){
var query = "SELECT OfferId FROM SHOPPING_PERFORMANCE_REPORT WHERE " +
FILTERS + " DURING "+ TIME_DURATION;
var products = [];
var count = 0;
var report = AdWordsApp.report(query);
var rows = report.rows();
while (rows.hasNext()){
var row = rows.next();
var offer_id = row['OfferId'].toString();
products.push([offer_id]);
count+= 1;
}
  
Logger.log(count);
return products;
}

function pushToSpreadsheet(data){
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("GOOGLE SHEET EINFÜGEN");
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Custom_Label');
var lastRow = sheet.getMaxRows();
sheet.getRange('A2:A'+lastRow).clearContent();
var start_row=2;
var endRow=start_row+data.length-1;
var range = sheet.getRange('A'+start_row+':'+'A'+endRow);
if (data.length>0){range.setValues(data);}
return;
}
```

I have already tried to modify the script, but it didn't work. I think it has something to do with the raw data from Google Ads. Does anyone know more?